# Getting Error: "Illegal assignment from List<AggregateResult> to List<ReportsColumnMap__c>"

Tags: aggregateresult

Here is my code
`

```
global with sharing class ReportsListController {

   public String dcarr { get; set; }
   public static ReportsColumnMap__c repcols { get; set; }
   public ReportsListController() { } // empty constructor

  @RemoteAction
  global static List<ReportsColumnMap__c> getRepCols(String dcarr) {        
    List<ReportsColumnMap__c> repcols = 
        [SELECT ColumnName__c,SObject__c ,COUNT(ID) FROM ReportsColumnMap__c WHERE ColumnName__c IN ('OWNER','FIRST_NAME','LAST_NAME','TITLE','COMPANY','LEAD_SOURCE','RATING','STREET','EMAIL') AND SObject__c !='null' GROUP BY SObject__c ,ColumnName__c];
    return repcols;
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 2):

As you are doing Aggregate query so it will result List

```
List<AggregateResult> repcols = 
        [SELECT ColumnName__c,SObject__c ,COUNT(ID) FROM ReportsColumnMap__c WHERE ColumnName__c IN ('OWNER','FIRST_NAME','LAST_NAME','TITLE','COMPANY','LEAD_SOURCE','RATING','STREET','EMAIL') AND SObject__c !='null' GROUP BY SObject__c ,ColumnName__c];

for (AggregateResult ar : repcols )  {
    System.debug('ColumnName__c' + ar.get('ColumnName__c'));
    System.debug('SObject__c ' + ar.get('SObject__c '));
}
```

Then you need to create `List<ReportsColumnMap__c>` and can return it or simple return the `List<AggregateResult> repcols`